# StringUtils.defaultString euphemism for collections?

Tags: java, collections, null

Is there an analogous method to StringUtils.defaultString for collections, so you can avoid checking for null value, since in most cases, the desired effect is the same as if it were an empty list?

e.g. to replace

```
if (list != null) {
    for (String item: list) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

with something like

```
for (String item: ListUtils.defaultList(list)) {
    // ...
}
```

Using the ternary operator is pretty ugly and cause unchecked casting errors:

```
List<String> safelista = (List<String>) (list != null ? list : Collections.emptyList());
List<String> safelistb = (list != null ? list : Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
```

Putting it inline is even uglier.

Comment: Nice idea, something like Commons Lang's `StringUtils.trimToEmpty()`, but for collections.

Comment: You can avoid the cast in your ternary operators by using `List<String> safelista = (list != null ? list : Collections.<String>emptyList());`. Though that doesn't address your *actual* issue.

Comment: Have reported this idea as an enhancement to google-collections... see http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/issues/detail?id=299

Answer (score 3):

Do you have control over the method which returns the list in question? If so, I'd change it so that it never returns null, but just an empty list for the case that. That's also more the normal convention.

Comment: No, in this case it's a method parameter, although I agree this is a good convention.  I always make sure to initialize my collection fields to the appropriate empty collection.

Comment: Then I'd go for just a nullcheck and if necessary throw `IllegalArgumentException`. Or (my recommendation) just ignore it all and assume that it is never null (document it in the method's javadoc though that it requires a non-null collection and may throw NPE or IAE for the case that).

Comment: I use a precondition that the parameter cannot be null and force the caller to do the right thing... (so if(x list == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("list cannot be null"); and then I never have to worry about nulls).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the tertiary operator, you must define a helper function which uses `if()`:

```
public static <T> List<T> nullToEmpty (List<T> list) {
    if (list == null)
       return Collections.emptyList(); // Can't use ?: here!
    return list;
}
```

Comment: or, slightly more generally, `<T> List<T> nullToEmpty (List<? extends T> list)`

Comment: Doesn't make sense in this case. I return exactly the same list.